# Query is returning a single concatenated string of values THEN the rows it found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm getting some really weird results from my `QUERY()` Here is an image with an example:

[image]

I'm querying for the name where No Show = "No Show". It find the correct name `Name 5` but also returns a concatenated list of names separated by a space.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third, optional, argument of [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) command is

> The number of header rows at the top of data. If omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data.

In your situation, the formatting of column A confused the query, and it interpreted most of that column as header rows. Solution: explicitly indicate the number of header rows, i.e., 1 in your case.

Comment: Ah, in my case I would actually set it to 0 because I am not including the header rows in my query. And it worked!

Comment: THANK YOU, @user79865! I was stumped on a similar case and you nailed it!